# Is there a way to find out if I trained other than by visiting a trainer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How else can I determine if I trained at my current level?

Knowing this will help me by telling me if I still need to capitalize on the option, minus the tedium of searching for a trainer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reset the training counter with the console?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41114/how-do-you-reset-the-training-counter-with-the-console). That question is a few years old, but I still can't find any reference to the console values you'd need to determine this.

Comment: @psyk0 I don't even mention console, and I don't want to reset it. The answer to the question you suggest would not be an answer to my question. For example, even if there is a console command to reset the training counter, that doesn't let me find out if I trained this level.

Comment: @psyk0 Not even remotely similar.

Answer (score 5):

To tell if you've trained, you can use the console command:

```
getgs sCanNotTrainAnymore
```

It will print something like:

```
'You must level up to train more'
```

Took me a while to figure that out but I learned that there are **Game Settings** such as this that can be fetched set with `getgs` and `setgs`.

There is also `getglobalvalue` to fetch **Global Variables** such as the hour of the day:

```
getglobalvalue gamehour
```

which should print something like:

> ```
> GetGlobalValue>>8.97
> ```

The **Game Settings** and **Global Variables** can all be seen using the [TES5Edit](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25859) program.   All global variables can also be printed to the console with:

```
showglobalvars
```

Another category are the **General Stats** such are gold found which are viewable in the escape menu.   If you want to get these with the console its:

```
GetPCmiscstat "Gold Found"
```

Hope this is still useful to people.

Comment: `getgs sCanNotTrainAnymore` prints 'You must level up to train more.' regardless of whether or not you can train. It's just the string used when you can't train more. I suspect that the setting exists for localization purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check how many times a particular skill has been trained at a trainer without visiting a trainer of that skill. The only surefire way of knowing is to simply level up to reset that cap back to 5 (but then you wouldn't get to capitalize on those uses!).

Comment: i don't know if this answers the question. i think what he want to know is, "how do i know if i trained in my current level or not".

Answer (score -1):

The only other way seems to be by keeping track of the "Training Sessions" statistic of GENERAL of GENERAL STATS.